Getting Error: astrapy.core.api.APIRequestError while trying to connect to astradb
I am getting astrapy.core.api.APIRequestError while trying to connect to AstraDB, I am aware what error is saying but I did not find any solution.
Complete Error:
astrapy.core.api.APIRequestError: {"errors":[{"message":"No \"findCollections\" command found as \"GeneralCommand\"","errorCode":"NO_COMMAND_MATCHED"}]}
Code:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_astradb import AstraDBVectorStore
from langchain.agents import create_tool_calling_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor

from langchain.tools.retriever import create_retriever_tool
from langchain import hub
from langchain_community.llms import ollama
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_huggingface.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from github import fetch_github_issues

# load env variables
load_dotenv()

# connect to vectordb
def connect_to_vstore():
    embeddings=HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
    ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT = os.getenv("ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT")
    ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN = os.getenv("ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN")
    desired_namespace = os.getenv("ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE")

    if desired_namespace:
        ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE = desired_namespace
    else:
        ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE = None

    vstore = AstraDBVectorStore(
        embedding=embeddings,
        collection_name="github",
        api_endpoint=ASTRA_DB_API_ENDPOINT,
        token=ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN,
        namespace=ASTRA_DB_KEYSPACE,       # name of the database or table
    )
    return vstore

vstore = connect_to_vstore()

Could you please provide me any workaround/solution. so that I can do similarity search from astradb.

Looks like you're maybe following this tutorial though using different embeddings and LLM. I'm pretty sure the code, as it is, should work. So I'm wondering if there's something to do with either loading your environment variables or the version of LangChain and AstraPy you're using. Can you first ensure that your env vars are in fact loaded correctly, and then let me know what version of those dependencies you have?

yes I have re-checked this multiple times, env variables are loaded properly.

I am using astrapy v1.2.1 and langchain v0.2.3 in this code.

I was working on the same code today. I found this answer in the YouTube comments as given below:
norminemralino2260
I got this issue also. The issue is that there seems to be an issue with the latest (0.3.2 and 0.3.3) versions of langchain_astradb. If you look at the requirements.txt from Tim's github repo it points to langchain-astradb==0.2.0. You can manually fix this issue by calling "pip3 install langchain-astradb==0.2.0" acutally even langchain-astradb==0.3.1 worked for me.
Thanks to norminemralino2260
